# Am I using falsetto in this audio recording ? (vocal range test)

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I wanted to test my vocal range, and test how high I can go without forcing too much and *without* using falsetto. I tried to sing C4 to C5-D5 (I did 3 recordings), but I have the feeling that above B4 I'm forced to sing in falsetto (the last note which is D5 is definitely falsetto).

Can you tell me how high I can go without switching into falsetto?

Here are the 3 recordings :

- https://vocaroo.com/i/s139fbfb2FFG
- https://vocaroo.com/i/s0dnwmMTn4X5
- https://vocaroo.com/i/s0NdW0M141e7

Comment: As Laurence Payne notes below, it would help if you could sing something where you're definitely in chest voice so we can hear the difference. Also, your age might be of importance; have you gone through a voice change?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me that you're in falsetto all the way!   Or at least in such a light head voice as makes no difference.

Let's hear something starting (at least) an octave lower?

Answer (score 0):

One technique a teacher showed me once (so, not a very scientific method) is to lightly touch the sides of you throat (or adam's apple, if you're a male) and start going up your range. When you stop feeling the vibration, it means you're using falsetto.

Disclaimer: I'm not a professional singer or teacher, so this may be very anecdotal.